# Parsing positional record file with n-level hierarchy using FileHelper library

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, parsing, filehelpers

I am trying to use FileHelper library for parsing a text file. Ultimately the data would be stored in database. My text file contains positional records. The first two chars of the record define there position in the hierarchy of the records.
The file is ordered in the following manner:

- 10 Common Data (10-19 all have the same level)

  - 20 2nd level Data (20-29 have the same level)

    - 30 3rd level data (30-39 have the same level)

      - 40 4th level Data

        - 50 5th level data

          - 60 Last level Data
          - 60 Last level Data
        - 50 5th level data

          - 60 Last level Data
          - 60 Last level Data
      - 40 4th level Data

        - 50 5th level data

          - 60 Last level Data
          - 60 Last level Data
        - 50 5th level data

          - 60 Last level Data
          - 60 Last level Data
    - 30 3rd level data

      - repeated sequence of 40, 50, 60..
  - 20 2nd level Data

    - repeated sequence of 20, 40, 50, 60.. and so on...

Now i am trying to use the Master-Detail concept of FileHelper but i guess it only works  for one level of Master-Detail. Can it be used to create a hierarchy of data which then can be used to fill the relevant tables? All the records are Fixed length records so no problem there.

**Caution: there is no primary-foreign key relation between the records. The position and the record number tells who is the parent(master) and who are there children(details).**

Sample date is given below:

```
10R 420120320F 20120320212045 16
11F FFuture              
11C OCall                
11P OPut                 
12CADCanadian Dollars     0
12CHFSwiss Francs         0
12CZKCzech Republic Korun 0
12DEMGerman Marks         0
12DKKDanish Krone         0
12ESBSpanish Pesatas      3
12EUREuropean currency Un 0
12FIMFinnish Mark         0
14     1 20.0000    100 2O  UKX 1A 1L  Z   1B 1
14     2 20.0000    100 2L  EFE 1A 1O  EFE 1B 1
14     3 20.0000    100 2L  EFP 1A 1O  EFP 1B 1
14     4 20.0000    100 2L  CCI 1A 1O  CCI 1B 1
14     5 20.0000    100 2L  AXI 1A 1O  AXI 1B 1
14     6 20.0000    100 2L  BLI 1A 1O  BLI 1B 1
15  1F+0, VOL+        2
15  2F+0, VOL-        1
15  3F+1/3, VOL+      4
15  4F+1/3, VOL-      3
15  5F-1/3, VOL+      6
15 16F-EXTREME       16
16EQYLIFFE Equities           
16IPEIntl. Petroleum Exchange 
16LCPLIFFE Commodity Products 
16LIFLIFFE Financials         
16LIGLIFFE OTC                
16LMELME Metals               
20L  LIFFE   F 
30AXIAEX Index              EQYEUR2.000.3500        10 110 1        
31 1 10000000099999999
32  1       220 2 1 1A 1 1B
34 1 1 1 1
40ZAXFAEX Index Future    EUR 10000    10       0.02000    1.00     0     0 2000002
50201204000.0000000.25000.2500  120120400
60       0F     1 3308420   1.0000      0      0 -66667 -66667  66667  66667-133333-133333 133333 133333-200000-200000 200000 200000-140000 140000
50201205000.0000000.25000.2500  120120500
60       0F     1 3262910   1.0000      0      0 -66667 -66667  66667  66667-133333-133333 133333 133333-200000-200000 200000 200000-140000 140000
50201206000.0000000.25000.2500  120120600
60       0F     1 3258970   1.0000      0      0 -66667 -66667  66667  66667-133333-133333 133333 133333-200000-200000 200000 200000-140000 140000
40I  OTHREE MONTH EURO (EUEUR 10000    25       0.25000    1.00     3  1000   32002
50201204000.0000000.35000.3500  120120600
60   97750C     1   16000   1.0000      0      0  -1067  -1067   1067   1067  -2133  -2133   2133   2133  -3200  -3200   3200   3200  -2240   2240
60   97750P     1       0   0.0000      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
60   97875C     1   14750   1.0000      0      0  -1067  -1067   1067   1067  -2133  -2133   2133   2133  -3200  -3200   3200   3200  -2240   2240
60   97875P     1       0   0.0000      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
30L  3 Month Pound Sterli   LIFGBP2.000.3500         11010 1        
31 6 10000000020120600 22012090020121200 32013030020131200 42014030020141200 52015030020151200 62016030099999999
32  1        50 2 2 1A 2 1B
32  2        55 2 1 1A 1 1B
32 21       290 2 6 1A 6 1B
34 2 1 1 3 2 4 6
```

Please anybody can guide me in how to use FileHelper or any other library or some algorithm to parse this. Using XML in this can be a problem as file size is huge (100 Mb's) so I would prefer a non-xml based approach (my previous approach was XML based and was rejected by my architect).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileHelpers is not really designed for formats that complex.  You might get somewhere with the [MultiRecord engine](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/example_multirecords.html) if you define a separate format for each row and parse them all based on the start of line, but you will find it tricky to link child records with parent records.

I think your best approach would be to code it manually.  Something like

1. Read in line per line
2. Split each line into fields
3. If it is a master line, read in detail lines
4. If the detail lines are masters for further detail, read those lines... etc.

If the file size is big, then you should not try to process the whole without saving the parsed parts somewhere (a database).

There are some interesting approaches for handling the parsing of the CSV grammar.  You could use [Linq](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/02/linq-query-comma-separated-value-csv.html) which does not tend to give very helpful error messages when there is a parsing problem.  Or you could use ExpandoObjects as described [here](http://craigwatson1962.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/csv-expandoobject-and-linq/).  Another way would be to use a parser generator like [Sprache](http://code.google.com/p/sprache/).  Regardless, these approaches are likely to run into memory problems if you try to handle the whole file.  My advice would be to consider them for parsing the individual lines.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this.
I figured that out after spending two days on file helper(multi-record engine). So i am following something similar as mentioned by you.
1. Read line by line
2. Create a hierarchy of objects(one class per record-type)
3. Let the responsibility of parsing the fields in the line be with the individual class.
4. Implement (by each class) some sort of Interface for saving their fields in database and then disposing itself off.
5. Just check that parent saves before the child saves but disposes after all its children are done saving.

Answer (score -1):

1. approach    You can parse the files using regular expression this is a general idea
2. Split and win

   2.1. Split in lines

   2.2. Split the lines in words. Regarding n words you know what format you expect

   2.3. if 2.2 is not enough apply a regular expression for line to get the data.

   2.4. if 2.3 is not enough maybe you have regions, header, financial info 1, financial info 2, use 2.1 and 2.2 to know where you are, and save you state,  use this state to apply rules that you need.